# How to delete a file that is open for normal I/O?

Tags: c#, stream

How to delete a file that is open for normal I/O?

I want to decrypt the file. If the code is incorrect then I need to delete the output file.

I can't use `File.Delete()` because:

**Windows NT 4.0 Platform Note: Delete does not delete a file that is open for normal I/O or a file that is memory mapped.**

```
try
{
    FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete);
    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete);

    PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76});
    Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

    alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
    alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    int bufferLen = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
    int bytesRead;

    do
    {
        bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead != 0);

    cs.Close();
    fsIn.Close();
    return true;
}
catch(Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect code :(");
    return false;
}
```

Somebody knows how I can delete the output file?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is already in your question.

> Delete does not delete a file that is open for normal I/O.

So, close the file, and then you can delete it.

You should also wrap your file streams in `using` blocks to ensure that the unmanaged resources will be tidied up in a timely and predictable fashion. Like this:

```
using (FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(...))
{
    ....
}
```

This is the best way to make sure that your file is closed when you have finished with it. You can put your call to `File.Delete` after the `using` block.

Finally, I'm pretty sure that you don't want to use `FileShare.Delete`. For example, on your input file that will allow other processes to delete the file while you are operating on it. You want `FileShare.Read` on the file that you are reading, and `FileShare.None` on the file that you are writing.